Jooq Automatic Mapping for 1:1 Relationship containing 1:N relationship
I have following DTOs:

ProductDTO

UserDTO

UserRoleDTO:

I need to fetch a list of Products and each of those Products has a field "creatorId" (NULLABLE).

For the creatorId i need to fetch the corresponding User (1:1 relationship),

and for this User i need to fetch his roles (1:N relationship)





Product -> 1:1 -> User -> 1:N -> UserRoles

I got this to work with following jooq query:
dsl()
    .select(
            asterisk(),
            multiset(
                    selectDistinct(
                            asterisk()
                    )
                            .from(UserRole.USER_ROLE)
                            .where(UserRole.USER_ROLE.USERID.eq(Product.PRODUCT.CREATORID))
            ).as("roles")),
    .from(Product.PRODUCT)
        .leftJoin(User.USER)
        .on(User.USER.USERID.eq(Product.PRODUCT.CREATORID))
    .where(...)
    .groupBy(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID)
    .orderBy(...)
    .offset(...)
    .limit(...)
    .fetch().map(new RecordMapper<Record, ProductDTO>() {
        @Override
        public @Nullable ProductDTO map(Record record) {
            ProductDTO product = rec.into(ProductDTO.class);
            UserDTO creator = rec.into(UserDTO.class);
            List<UserRoleDTO> creatorRoles = rec.get("roles", Result.class).into(UserRoleDTO.class);
            creator.setRoles(creatorRoles);
            product.setCreator(creator);

            return product;
        }
    });

Now my question:
is this mapping also possible "implicitly" without the explicit "RecordMapper" part, so the mapping is reusable with less boilerplate for different statements (fetch, fetchCount, fetchStream) ? <-- (also possible in this example, but RecordMapper must be defined on each of the statements again)
Im already satisfied i got this to work, as i only found examples for using multiset with direct 1:N relationships, but what i have here is a 1:1 relationship that (on a deeper level) also contains a 1:N relationship.

Normally one could just make two separate SELECT-Statements, but for my use-case (Remote-Pagination with Filtering), it is necessary that all! relationships are processed in one single SELECT-Statements, so i can use the join-statements for additional filtering on the query.

Why not use the recommended approach using ad-hoc converters?

Hello Lukas, thanks for your tip, i have posted an answer, where i now got it to work with help of ad-hoc converts. My answer does not look really elegant, but it does what it should (do the conversion before! the execution of the statement, so the conversion can stay in the abstraction) So it is kind-of implicitly in my answer. If you know of a even more elegant way maybe you can reanswer there :)

Again, thank you for your consistent answers! much appreciated and i have learned much in the process :)

Some general rules of thumb:

You should almost never need to use the asterisk() operator
You should almost never need to use .class literals in your mappers (which use reflection, which isn't type safe). Of course you can still do this, it's supported in principle, but then, you won't know if you wrote a correct query and mapping until you run it.
You should almost never need to manually extract values from results or set values to DTOs

Doesn't this look much simpler?
dsk().select(

         // Project the PRODUCT fields
         PRODUCT.ID,
         PRODUCT.NAME,
         ...

         // Nest a projection of USER fields (using implicit joins)
         row(PRODUCT.user().ID, PRODUCT.user().NAME, ...).mapping(UserDTO::new),

         // Nest a collection of USER_ROLE fields (using join path correlation)
         multiset(
             select(
                 PRODUCT.user().role().ID, 
                 PRODUCT.user().role().NAME, ...)
             .from(PRODUCT.user().role())
         ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(UserRoleDTO::new))))
    .from(PRODUCT)
    .where(...)
    .orderBy(...)
    .offset(...)
    .limit(...)
    .fetch(Records.mapping(ProductDTO::new));

This is assuming you design your DTOs like this, for example:
record UserRoleDTO(long id, String name, ...) {}
record UserDTO(long id, String name, ...) {}
record ProductDTO(long id, String name, UserDTO creator, List<UserRoleDTO> roles) {}

For simplicity, the above is using

jOOQ 3.19 join path correlation
jOOQ 3.11 implicit joins

Both of these features really simplify these MULTISET queries, though, they're obviously optional. You can still use explicit joins if you prefer that.
Reusing the query for a COUNT(*) value
Rather than running an extra round trip to count the outcome of a query, there's an option of using window functions instead, to calculate the COUNT(*) value in a single query.
Though, given that the COUNT(*) value is independent of the whole USER and USER_ROLE nesting, perhaps running 2 seperate queries is better anyway, where the COUNT(*) query omits all the nested data, depending on how exactly you intend to present pagination.

i replicated your example without any errors now, but sadly i get a runtime error during execution. When i remove the row() part the error goes away and the query executes successfully.
set @@group_concat_max_len = @t;]; (conn=1879) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.userId,     alias_2438556.clientId as v8.clientId,     alias_2438556.email a...' at line 12

i simplified the example as much as i could, to still produce the error for me. And the following is the shorted example that still produces the runtime-error:
dsl().select(PRODUCT.PRODUCTID,  row(PRODUCT.fk_product_creatorId().USERID))                .from(Product.PRODUCT);

@funkrusher: That seems unrelated, and hard to help you with in the comments section here. Can you please ask a new question, with all the necessary details?

Hello Lukas, regarding your here mentioned "rules of thumb" can you tell me if those can only be followed / applied if the Table in the Query contains max 22 Columns? It seems to me that as soon as a table contains more columns than 22, the typesafe approach is no longer applicable, and then the other approach can/should be chosen (or the table refactored)

@funkrusher: These are rules of thumb, so there are always exceptions. Chances are, that with large projections, you're going to nest attributes that belong together, so you'll still be able to stay under the limit of 22 from a jOOQ perspective. But ultimately, many roads lead to Rome. Do what fits best for you.

With help from Lukas Eder (see above) and the linked examples-page to ad-hoc converters

see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/
also relevant, multiset: https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/



the Conversion is done before! the execution of the statement, as desired in the question.
the Conversion is not really implicit, as the ad-hoc converter must be configured for the exact use-case (nullable 1:1 relationship with a 1:N sublist)

That way this code can be reused for different use-cases (fetch(), fetchStream(), ...) without the need to redeclare the converter on the results of those different use-case function, but the conversion can be centralized together with this DSL-Statement for reuse.
SelectFinalStep<? extends Record> selectStep = dsl()
    .select(
        asterisk(),
        multiset(
            selectDistinct(
                asterisk(),
                multiset(
                    selectDistinct(
                        asterisk()
                    )
                    .from(UserRole.USER_ROLE)
                    .where(UserRole.USER_ROLE.USERID.eq(User.USER.USERID))
                ).as("roles")
            )
            .from(User.USER)
            .where(User.USER.USERID.eq(Product.PRODUCT.CREATORID))
        ).as("creator").convertFrom(r -> {
            // multiset always gives us a list-result, 
            // but we expect a nullable 1:1 relationship here for sure...
            if (r.isEmpty()) {
                return (UserDTO) null;
            } else {
                Record first = r.getFirst();
                List<UserRoleDTO> roles = first.get("roles", Result.class).into(UserRole.USER_ROLE).into(UserRoleDTO.class);
                return first.into(User.USER).into(UserDTO.class).setRoles(roles);
            }
        })
    )
    .from(Product.PRODUCT)
    .leftJoin(User.USER)
    .on(User.USER.USERID.eq(Product.PRODUCT.CREATORID))
    .where(...)
    .groupBy(Product.PRODUCT.PRODUCTID)
    .orderBy(...)
    .offset(...)
    .limit(...);

// case1 - selecting
selectStep.fetchInto(ProductDTO.class);

// case2 - counting
dsl().fetchCount(selectStep);

// case3 - streaming
selectStep.fetchStreamInto(ProductDTO.class);


Why not apply the conversion at every nesting level, though? 1) you should never need to use asterisk(), 2) you should never need to use the .class literals and reflection. This can be done in a completely type safe way.

Regarding the counting, why is this needed? Pagination? Have you considered using a window function to calculate this count value directly with your query itself to avoid extra round trips? See this article for an example


i use asterisk() because the DTOs are changed often over time.. we work in SCRUM sprints, and add/remove features very often. The code changes often. With asterisk() all the fields in the DTO are mapped automatically. Otherwise developers need to change all places where the fields have been used in selects, when a field is added/changed/removed via db-schema migration. If there is something inherintly wrong in this approach i would be happy for finding out, but i found asterisk() pretty comfortable, and sure often not all fields are needed all the time, but in most our cases they are.


in my example i tried applying the conversion in every nested level. But when i apply the conversion on the as("roles") i got an runtime error in the SQL execution, that i could not solve. It seemed only to work when i apply the conversion only on the "creator" multiset and not the "roles" multiset.

i will read about the window function for (maybe) making the count in one statement and avoid the extra roundtrip, thx. Did not know that is possible.


I have used the Jooq-Generated Pojos as source for my DTOs, but have removed the constructors... maybe i should also copy those, when they can help with tsafety :D


Well, the thing that is inherently "wrong" is 1) that you'll end up projecting way too much data and it will be very hard to fix this later on in your development cycles, so there's a performance issue waiting here, at least in a lot of cases (you said not in yours, though). 2) the asterisk will generate a column order as specified in the (production) database, unlike what jOOQ's code generator may have expected at compile time, so there may be rare, subtle errors related to that. Perhaps better project Table.fields(), or just the Table directly.

Regarding the runtime exception, it's really much better if you can just show a simple reproducer than describe it with words...

thanks Lukas, i will ask a new question for the error, and i will also replace the asterisk and try to use the consctructors for type safe mapping instead.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

While the accpeted answer is the best way to solve this with a clean setup, looking at some tables in my project that have more than 22 columns (which is rare), i decided to use this different approach that (should) also be typesafe but is not as flexible, as it always takes all fields of each table into account (which is good for my usecase).
dsl()
    .select(
        row(
            // Project the PRODUCT table
            PRODUCT,

            // USER fields and corresponding ROLES via join path (1:1 containing 1:N)
            row(
                PRODUCT.creator(),
                multiset(
                    select(
                        PRODUCT.creator().user_role()
                    ).from(PRODUCT.creator().user_role())
                ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(RoleDTO::create))
            ).convertFrom(UserDTO::createOrNull),

            // PRODUCT_LANG 1:N via join path
            multiset(
                select(
                    PRODUCT.product_lang()
                ).from(PRODUCT.product_lang())
            ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(ProductLangDTO::create))
        ).convertFrom(ProductDTO::create)
    )

In this approach i make use of the fact that jOOQ automatically Maps "Table" definitions within "row()" block to the corresponding (codegenerated) Record-Classes. The only thing missing then, is to map those Record-Classes to the DTO-Classes, for which Constructors/Functions within the DTOs can be defined that create DTOs from RecordN.
For example. The Constructurs/Functions for the example are as follows:
ProductDTO:
    public static ProductDTO create(
        Record3<ProductRecord, UserDTO, List<ProductLangDTO>> r
    ) {
        ProductDTO product = new ProductDTO();
        product.from(r.value1());
        product.setCreator(r.value2());
        product.setLangs(r.value3());
        return product;
    }

UserDTO:
    public static @Nullable UserDTO createOrNull(
        Record2<UserRecord, List<RoleDTO>> r
    ) {
        UserRecord rec = r.value1();
        if (rec.getUserId() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
        user.from(r.value1())
        user.setRoles(r.value2());
        return user;
    }

The good thing... the DTOs themselve also contain "into"/"from" methods that are mapping typesafe. The developer should not forget, to add/remove new/changed fields here though, otherwise they would not be mapped. For example:
    @Override
    public void from(IUser from) {
        setUserId(from.getUserId());
        setClientId(from.getClientId());
        setEmail(from.getEmail());
        setFirstname(from.getFirstname());
        setLastname(from.getLastname());
    }

Therefore the Record to DTO mapping is typesafe and unproblematic.
